# Pass anon function in parameter to be used by Select

Tags: c#, linq

How do I pass a anon function in the parameter to be ran in a select statement?

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(Func<string> tokenFunc = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> tokens = Regex.Split(INPUT, @"(\d+|&|\||\(|\))").Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false);
        if (tokenFunc != null)
        {
            tokens = tokens.Select(tokenFunc);
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

What am I doing wrong?

I want to call it like this:

```
MyViewObj.Tokenize( (x) => { if(x=='1') return 1; else return 0; });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `tokenFunc` it should be of type `Func<TSource, TResult>` and you are supplying `Func<TResult>`.

Naively, looking at how you are calling it, it should become:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(Func<string, int> tokenFunc = null)
{
    IEnumerable<string> tokens = Regex.Split(INPUT, @"(\d+|&|\||\(|\))").Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false);
    if (tokenFunc != null)
    {
        tokens = tokens.Select(tokenFunc);
    }
}
```

But this will, of course, fail, as you are trying to assign the result to `IEnumerable<string>` but are effectively returning `IEnumerable<int>`

To make it all work together you need to change things to `Func<string, string>` and return `"0"` or `"1"` instead of `0` or `1` in your call:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(Func<string, string> tokenFunc = null)
{
    IEnumerable<string> tokens = Regex.Split(INPUT, @"(\d+|&|\||\(|\))").Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false);
    if (tokenFunc != null)
    {
        tokens = tokens.Select(tokenFunc);
    }
}
```

And change the calling code to:

```
MyViewObj.Tokenize( (x) => { if(x=="1") return "1"; else return "0"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a Func taking string as input and returning your return type:

```
Func<string,int> tokenFunc
```